# Ejecutar operación escrita en el arreglo C++

Tags: c++, array, compilador

Necesito hacer la operación de varios números desde un arreglo tipo *string*. Supongamos que ingreso *5000+5*, este debe dar como resultado *5005*. Logro hacer la operación con 2 números *3*3=9*, lo que necesitaría es algo que recorra el arreglo y me lo divida en 3 partes.

1. El primer número.
2. El segundo número.
3. El operador, que puede ser `+`, `-`, `*` o `/`.

Ambos números convertirlos de *string* a *int* para luego segun la operacion ingresada en el array tipo string se ejecute. De esta forma, arroje el resultado adecuado.

Código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, 
system("pause") or input loop */
using namespace std;
int der, izq, i, pos, cont=0, rst; 
char cadena[10];

int main()
{
    cout<<"Digite la cadena: ";
    cin>> cadena;

    for (i=0;cadena[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        cont++;
    }

    cout <<"\n La cantidad de caracteres es: " <<cont;

    for (i=0;cadena[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
    if (cadena[i]=='+')
        {
            pos=i;
            rst= int (cadena[pos-1]) -'0'+int (cadena[pos+1]-'0');
        }       

        if (cadena[i]=='-')
    {
            pos=i;
            rst = int (cadena[pos-1]) -'0'-int (cadena[pos+1]-'0');
        }       

        if (cadena[i]=='*')
        {
            pos=i;
            rst= int (cadena[pos-1]) -'0'*int (cadena[pos+1]-'0');
        }       

        if (cadena[i]=='/')
        {
            pos=i;
            rst= int (cadena[pos-1]) -'0'/int (cadena[pos+1]-'0');
        } 
    }

    cout <<"\n El num1 es "<<cadena[pos-1];
    cout <<"\n El operador es "<<cadena[pos];
    cout <<"\n El num2 es "<<cadena[pos+1];
    cout <<"\n El resultado es "<<rst<<endl;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu pregunta? ¿Qué problema tienes con este código?

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer la operación no necesitas actuar sobre un único caracter, sino que tienes que gestionar cada secuencia de números al completo. De otra forma no serás capaz de tratar correctamente detalles como el acarreo.

En primero lugar yo usaría `std::string` en vez de `char*`. Para pegarme con los punteros en cosas tan básicas como la gestión de cadenas me quedo en C:

```
std::string cadena;
std::cin >> cadena;
```

Lo siguiente es extraer de `cadena` los dos números y el operador:

```
std::string numero1, numero2;
char operador;

std::string* numeroActual = &numero1;
for( char c : cadena )
{
  if (c < '0' || c > '9' )
  {
    operador = c;
    numeroActual = &numero2;
  }
  else
  {
    *numeroActual += c;
  }
}
```

Ahora, por comodidad, vamos a invertir la secuencia de dígitos de cada número. Lo hacemos así porque las operaciones matemáticas se realizan del dígito menos representativo al más representativo y con este paso tan tonto reducimos la complejidad del algoritmo al ahorrarnos unas cuantas comprobaciones:

```
std::reverse(std::begin(numero1), std::end(numero1));
std::reverse(std::begin(numero2), std::end(numero2));
```

El siguiente paso sería normalizar los números. Puede suceder que las secuencias tengan tamaños diferentes. Para no andar metiendo condicionales que ensucien los algoritmos lo mejor es añadir '0's hasta que ambas secuencias tengan la misma longitud.

Como las secuencias están invertidas, los ceros hay que añadirlos al final:

```
while( numero1.length() < numero2.length() )
  numero1 += '0';

while( numero2.length() < numero1.length() )
  numero2 += '0';
```

Y ahora ya podemos empezar a obrar la magia. Lo primero la función para sumar:

```
std::string suma(std::string const& numero1, std::string const& numero2)
{
  std::string resultado;

  char acarreo = 0;
  for( size_t i=0; i<numero1.size(); ++i )
  {
    char a = numero1[i] - '0';
    char b = numero2[i] - '0';
    char c = a + b + acarreo;
    if( c > 9 )
    {
      acarreo = 1;
      c -= 10;
    }
    else
    {
      acarreo = 0;
    }

    resultado += (c + '0');
  }

  return resultado;
}
```

Y ahora la lógica de negocio:

```
std::string resultado;
switch( operador )
{
  case '+':
    resultado = suma(numero1, numero2);
}

// Las secuencias originales estaban invertidas, luego el resultado también lo estará
std::reverse(std::begin(resultado), std::end(resultado));
std::cout << resultado;
```